# AWS Connect - Connect Existing SIP infra as inbound to AWS Connect IVR

Tags: amazon-web-services, ivr, amazon-connect

Any way to connect Amazon connect for the IVR Flow from the existing SIP Infra? Does any one aware of this.

Based on public documentation i see they mentioned about only DID as the inbound to the AWS Connect IVR. Any other ways to the get the inbound call inside the IVR espcially routed from existing SIP.